# appsettings.json warning "value must be one of the following types"

Tags: visual-studio, appsettings

I have this object in my appsettings.json:

[image]

I keep getting a warning about RedisTarget and IncludeScopes: `Value must be one of the following types: object`. I don't understand what this warning means, why I should care, and there's no code associated with this warning that I can click to read up on, or surpress:

[image]

Can anyone shed light on what this warning is? My code works fine, and can read these values without issue. What's also weird is that if I change the name `Logging` to `logging` (lower case L), the warning disappears.